# Python appending a list to a list and then clearing it

Tags: python, list

I have this part of code isolated for testing purposes and this question

```
noTasks = int(input())
noOutput = int(input())
outputClist = []
outputCList = []

for i in range(0, noTasks):
    for w in range(0, noOutput):
        outputChecked = str(input())
        outputClist.append(outputChecked)
    outputCList.append(outputClist)
    outputClist[:] = []
print(outputCList)
```

I have this code here, and i get this output

```
[[], []]
```

I can't figure out how to get the following output, and i must clear that sublist or i get something completely wrong...

```
[["test lol", "here can be more stuff"], ["test 2 lol", "here can be more stuff"]]
```

Comment: `outputClist[:] = []` is **explicitly** removing everything you've put into the list already. I think you want `outputCList.append(outputClist[:])`, instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not quite what i had in mind but thanks for trying to help. The solution that Daniel posted worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python everything is a object. A list is a object with elements. You only create one object `outputclist` filling and clearing its contents. In the end, you have one list multiple times in `outputCList`, and as your last thing is clearing the list, this list is empty.

Instead, you have to create a new list for every task:

```
noTasks = int(input())
noOutput = int(input())
output = []

for i in range(noTasks):
    checks = []
    for w in range(noOutput):
        checks.append(input())
    output.append(checks)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the contained elements in `outputClist` to `outputCList` (not the greatest naming practice either to just have one capitalization partway through be the only difference in variable names), you are passing a reference to the list itself.  To get around this important and useful feature of Python that you don't want to make use of, you can pretty easily just pass a new list containing the elements of `outputClist` by changing this line

```
 outputCList.append(outputClist)
```

to

```
 outputCList.append(list(outputClist))
```

or equivalently, as @jonrsharpe states in his comment

```
 outputCList.append(outputClist[:])
```

Comment: Not quite what i had in mind but thanks for suggestion about naming. The solution Daniel posted worked.